uri balance in several haproxy servers
I have 3 haproxy nodes with the same config
backend nginx_cache
    balance uri path-only
    hash-type consistent
    option httpchk HEAD /ping/alive
    default-server check maxconn 32000
    fullconn 250000
    server test1 192.168.1.2:8080
    server test2 192.168.1.3:8080
    server test3 192.168.1.4:8080

How can I ensure that each of the HAProxy servers uses the same hashing algorithm and directs traffic to only one server for the same URI path?
I tried passing the path-server mapping to Redis via a Lua script, but I encountered issues with connecting Lua to the Redis cluster.
Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
